# Can I connect a single domain to two hosting service servers?

Tags: service, dns, hosting

If I do have a domain and hosting from an ISP, can I subscribe with another ISP for another hosting service?
By another hosting service (secondary service), I refer to act as backup to the first hosting, if something happens. 
And also, could both be working at the same time?

Comment: I recommend you question this again in the proper communities for this subject. It is the same login. https://serverfault.com/ and https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your help ^^ @Danmaxis